# Fancybox on Android browser

Tags: android, fancybox, tablet, mobile-website

I have a mobile site with fancybox popups
I'm having problems with close button:

```
<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:void(0);" id="fancyboxCloseButton"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
```

On Nexus 7 tablet with Android 4.4.4 I see the close button (X) with green color:

```
.fancybox-close {
position: absolute;
top: .5%;
right: 2%;
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 8040;
background: none!important;
font-size: 150%;
color: #afd732!important;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

But on Samsung tablet with Android 3.1 I see green holo square.

Since it impossible to debug Android 3.1 browser.
Any ideas what it can be?

Comment: try setting some `width` and `height` (which it's recommended for absolute positioned elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a font issue. Android none Chrome browser doesn't support `.woff` font.
I added `svg` font and that solved the problem.
The `fancybox` works fine in Android browser.